# validate current domain name extensions via a web service

Tags: web-services, validation

I am trying to build a form that validates email addresses and also company web site addresses for local companies that I am entering into the system.

It collects/validates the domain name extension - **.com, .org, .edu, .uk,** etc.

How can I keep it up to date given that domain extensions are being added over time?

We're a long way from just .com/.net/.org so it would be awesome to automate this more.

The technology I use is ruby on rails, but this general idea is applicable to JSP, Cold Fusion, ASP and other technologies with forms and validations.

Two great options would be:

1. A list (or array) of valid extensions (at that moment) that populates a  list.  The basic option is simply a list of valid extensions.  An advanced option might allow for getting descriptions with the extensions.
2. A service that will, for a given string, give a yes/no or true/false for if it's a currently valid domain extension.

Please note this is NOT the same need as met by email or domain name validation, this is for domain name **extensions**.

Answer (score 2):

You can use IANA's whois service to validate TLDs. They don't seem to have a dedicated service for it but you can query it using:

http://www.iana.org/cgi-bin/whois?q=com

You'll have to do some parsing after too though but the html is quite simple.

Comment: I'll give this an upcheck for useful information.  Unfortunately I cannot consider this 'the' correct answer as the service neither provides the list of extensions that I need nor an easy to understand way for me to use it to validate extensions on my server where I am using Ruby On Rails or on the client, presumably through a call there somehow.

Comment: I'm not too savvy in ruby but I can give you a c# example you can translate if that would help. I'm not sure that you should use client side validation even if that's possible to do.

Comment: Thanks!  yeah can't say I really love doing the client-side validation.  Would be simpler to have them submit, validate it on the backend and redisplay if invalid. However what most clients these days are liking to see is more front end validation without that critical page 'redraw'.  But don't worry it's not intended to populate a drop-down of domain extensions. That's wicked ugly IMHO!  Rather there would be an ajax call, upon changing the field value that would check the end (after the last 'dot') and then immediately display a message about the extension being invalid when that is the case

Comment: so yeah there's still going to be a back end call to validate the part after the last dot.  The string extraction I can figure out (though suggestions welcome), it's the server call to iana or another service that is key